# Sending file via bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Goal: I need to create a basic Android app where I can connect to nearby bluetooth devices and send them an image from my gallery with the click of a button. Here is what I have so far and I'm a bit confused as to where to go from here. (Its my first project in Android so go easy on me).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int Discover_duration = 300;
    private static final int request_bluetooth = 1;
    String path;
    private static final int Initial_request = 1337;
    private static final int request_write_storage = Initial_request + 4;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBTA = null;
    Button sendfile_button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sendfile_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendfile_button);


         mBTA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBTA == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not supported on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (!mBTA.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, request_bluetooth);
        }
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        mBTA.startDiscovery();

        //Register for Broadcasts when a device is discovered.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    }

}

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                //Bluetooth device has been discovered, retrive its info
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress();
            }
        }
    };

    @override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever read this answer ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6026313/3637559

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).